# Trouble with libgsl and wxwidget

Tags: wxwidgets, linker-errors, winmain

I'm having difficulty building a project in Windows 7 / Visual Studio 2010, and already spent longer than I would admit googling and fixing other errors to get to this point, but frustratingly I can't seem to get rid of the very last error. There is a linker error related to the _hypot function defined in math.h:

> wxTheAppInitializer" (?wxTheAppInitializer@@3VwxAppInitializer@@A)
>   already defined in main.obj 1>libgsl.a(linalg_svd.o) : error LNK2019:
>   unresolved external symbol _hypot referenced in function
>   _gsl_linalg_SV_decomp 1>libgsl.a(matrix_oper.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _hypot 1>libgsl.a(linalg_householder.o) :
>   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _hypot
>
> : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

When I follow the advice of [unresolved external symbol "_hypot" when using static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809275/unresolved-external-symbol-hypot-when-using-static-library) I get the following:

> 1>  Generating Code... 1> main.obj : error LNK2005: _hypot already
>   defined in About.obj 1> fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply
>   defined symbols found

Could anyone explain what is going on?

Comment: I realised that if I comment out _hypot in math.h altogether, and reimplement it in my main.cc as: 

#include <math.h>
extern "C"
{
 double hypot(double _X, double _Y)
 {
  return _hypot(_X, _Y);
 }
}

then I can build without errors. I think this is what the original post was getting at. But it seems like a really dirty fix. Can anyone suggest a cleaner fix without permanently editing math.h?

Answer (score 0):

Create .c file with the following contents:

```
extern double fabs(double);
extern double sqrt(double);

double hypot(double x, double y) {
  double ax = fabs(x), ay = fabs(y);
  double xy = x/y, yx = y/x;
  return ax > ay
    ? ax * sqrt(1.0 + yx*yx)
    : ay * sqrt(1.0 + xy*xy);
}
```

do not include math.h