# LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _hypot referenced in function _gsl_matrix_complex_long_double_div_elements

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to build a C++ Visual Studio 2005 solution in Visual Studio 2010.
I fixed some of upgrade issues so far when building the solution in the Visual Studio 2010.

However the last thing I do not know how to fix is the below link error message:

LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _hypot referenced in function _gsl_matrix_complex_long_double_div_elements in libgsl_d.lib.

Does anyone know of this issue?

TIA

Comment: Did you check to make sure all of the libraries you are using are from VS2010? It seems like one or more of your dependencies were not compiled with VS2010.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809275/unresolved-external-symbol-hypot-when-using-static-library